# Xamarin IOS Bluetooth LE advertising

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to write a `Xamarin`.IOS app that advertises a `BLE` service. When another user opens the app, they should be able to see all other users advertising from the same app (even if app is closed).

I'm finding the examples and explanation hard to come by. Currently, I can scan for devices using the `CBCentralManager`.

How do I go about advertising a service with a specific `GUID` so I can pick it up from another device?

Any examples or links will be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer Core Bluetooth framework. Following is the link :

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW1

Comment: Thank you. I used the link above to follow the guideline and am advertising a service off the device. I now face a new problem where all the devices I scanned show services = null. Even if I call periphial.DiscoverServices(). All devices have null service?

Comment: Before advertising you need to create service i.e instance of CBMutableService and add it to peripheral manager i.e instance of CBPeripheralManager.